# Align btn-group to other form-control input fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

I'm using Bootstrap to create an input field for a web application.

I'm using `btn-group` to create a segmented control of 3 selection (for users to select their sex). Unfortunately, I can't get it to behave how I would like.

I can't get the button group to be visually consistent with the other (text, email) input fields. I'd like for this control to be the same width as the other fields, with each of the 3 choices being the same width, each 1/3 the width of the whole.

- I've tried applying the `form-control` class. It gets the right size, but it create a duplicate outline.
- I've tried setting the button group to 100% width, with each button being 33% width. When I inspect the button group, it's the correct width, but most of it is blank space, with the children's width being unaffected.

  Male
      
      
          Female
      
      
          Other

Here's how it currently looks:

[image: currently]

Here's a rough mock-up of the desired outcome:

[image: desired]

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amomchilov/c3aLokcm/).

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 100%" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gcsru9go/

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer when the 15 minutes is up. May I ask how you knew about this? Do you know of any documentation listing all the available classes?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/  I'm not sure it lists all of them, but that one it does

Comment: I was on that page! Wonder how I could have missed that. Thanks!